# Separate object rotation values

Tags: transforms

Sorry but I don't know how to explain my problem. I am start working with blender.

I separate faces from cube.001 (black arrow) and set origin to center of mass of this new object(blue arrow). Than I try to get new transform location and rotation of this object. Unfortunately rotation is always 0 degrees. Can I somehow get world space values of rotation? Maybe some vector with euler angles between normals of this face and global axis?

[image]

Comment: I just separated this face from cube in Edit mode with <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*. Then in Object mode I set changed origin of the face with *Set Origin* > *Origin to Center of Mass* on the *Toolshelf*.

Comment: If your object was rotated in Object mode, separated face would have rotation values of the original. However from your screenshot it looks like your cube doesn't have rotation values changed; so the question is a bit unclear.